# How to unset Time-Based Token Keys feature

Tags: authentication, winter14, security-token, time-based-token-keys

We [added Time-Based Token Keys](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=add_time_based_token.htm&language=en_US) for our users but have since decided that we don't want to go down that route.

We [followed the instructions to remove the key](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_removing_two_factor_key.htm&language=en_US) and successfully removed the key.  However, the users are still presented with the Time-based token screen when logging in, prompting numerous complaints.  Does this just remove the key and not the feature?

Anyway, I would like to remove this feature altogether.  How do I do it?

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Somebody help please.